# How do I parse a complex JSON in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to parse a complex JSON in flutter,I have tried many things but I am not clear about the way things are happening.Can anyone explain how do I go about the situation:

```
{
  "message": {
    "header": {
      "status_code": 200,
      "execute_time": 0.021989107131958
    },
    "body": {
      "track_list": [
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 200357565,
            "track_name": "The Climb Back",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 99,
            "commontrack_id": 113835591,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 1,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 1,
            "num_favourite": 20,
            "album_id": 39278073,
            "album_name": "Lewis Street",
            "artist_id": 486280,
            "artist_name": "J. Cole",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/J-Cole\/The-Climb-Back?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/J-Cole\/The-Climb-Back\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-07-23T14:02:17Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 200187374,
            "track_name": "POPSTAR (feat. Drake)",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 99,
            "commontrack_id": 113684105,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 1,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 1,
            "num_favourite": 6,
            "album_id": 39216808,
            "album_name": "POPSTAR (feat. Drake) - Single",
            "artist_id": 24704782,
            "artist_name": "DJ Khaled feat. Drake, Lil Wayne & Rick Ross",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/DJ-Khaled-feat-Drake-Lil-Wayne-Rick-Ross\/POPSTAR-Drake?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/DJ-Khaled-feat-Drake-Lil-Wayne-Rick-Ross\/POPSTAR-Drake\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-07-17T13:38:30Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 200102123,
            "track_name": "What's Love Got to Do with It",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 99,
            "commontrack_id": 113606423,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 0,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 1,
            "num_favourite": 18,
            "album_id": 39186667,
            "album_name": "What's Love Got to Do with It",
            "artist_id": 45989671,
            "artist_name": "Kygo feat. Tina Turner",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Kygo-Tina-Turner\/What-s-Love-Got-to-Do-with-It?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Kygo-Tina-Turner\/What-s-Love-Got-to-Do-with-It\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-07-23T06:28:49Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 194169151,
            "track_name": "Blinding Lights",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 100,
            "commontrack_id": 104185748,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 0,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 1,
            "num_favourite": 5583,
            "album_id": 37216011,
            "album_name": "After Hours",
            "artist_id": 13937035,
            "artist_name": "The Weeknd",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/The-Weeknd-3\/Blinding-Lights?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/The-Weeknd-3\/Blinding-Lights\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-07-09T11:24:05Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": [
                {
                  "music_genre": {
                    "music_genre_id": 7,
                    "music_genre_parent_id": 34,
                    "music_genre_name": "Electronic",
                    "music_genre_name_extended": "Electronic",
                    "music_genre_vanity": "Electronic"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 198421234,
            "track_name": "Savage Love (Laxed - Siren Beat)",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 100,
            "commontrack_id": 112136372,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 1,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 1,
            "num_favourite": 454,
            "album_id": 38617941,
            "album_name": "Savage Love (Laxed - Siren Beat) - Single",
            "artist_id": 45643815,
            "artist_name": "Jawsh 685 feat. Jason Derulo",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Jawsh-685-Jason-Derulo\/Savage-Love-Laxed-Siren-Beat?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Jawsh-685-Jason-Derulo\/Savage-Love-Laxed-Siren-Beat\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-07-09T13:06:43Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 189626475,
            "track_name": "Watermelon Sugar",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 100,
            "commontrack_id": 104939195,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 0,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 1,
            "num_favourite": 567,
            "album_id": 36101498,
            "album_name": "Fine Line",
            "artist_id": 24505463,
            "artist_name": "Harry Styles",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Harry-Styles\/Watermelon-Sugar-2?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Harry-Styles\/Watermelon-Sugar-2\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2019-12-12T16:57:16Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 192324206,
            "track_name": "One Margarita",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 99,
            "commontrack_id": 107705631,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 0,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 1,
            "num_favourite": 62,
            "album_id": 36710192,
            "album_name": "Born Here Live Here Die Here",
            "artist_id": 360257,
            "artist_name": "Luke Bryan",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Luke-Bryan\/One-Margarita?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Luke-Bryan\/One-Margarita\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-03-13T08:54:41Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": [
                {
                  "music_genre": {
                    "music_genre_id": 34,
                    "music_genre_parent_id": 0,
                    "music_genre_name": "Music",
                    "music_genre_name_extended": "Music",
                    "music_genre_vanity": "Music"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 195445553,
            "track_name": "ROCKSTAR (feat. Roddy Ricch)",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 99,
            "commontrack_id": 109586143,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 1,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 1,
            "num_favourite": 687,
            "album_id": 37641727,
            "album_name": "BLAME IT ON BABY",
            "artist_id": 45035319,
            "artist_name": "DaBaby feat. Roddy Ricch",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/DaBaby-Roddy-Ricch\/ROCKSTAR-Roddy-Ricch?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/DaBaby-Roddy-Ricch\/ROCKSTAR-Roddy-Ricch\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-06-22T12:43:00Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 200340862,
            "track_name": "Patience",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 98,
            "commontrack_id": 113824017,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 0,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 0,
            "num_favourite": 4,
            "album_id": 39273295,
            "album_name": "Patience",
            "artist_id": 156,
            "artist_name": "Chris Cornell",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Chris-Cornell\/Patience?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Chris-Cornell\/Patience\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-07-21T20:15:22Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 200360270,
            "track_name": "Say Something",
            "track_name_translation_list": [],
            "track_rating": 1,
            "commontrack_id": 113837622,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 0,
            "has_lyrics": 1,
            "has_subtitles": 1,
            "has_richsync": 0,
            "num_favourite": 0,
            "album_id": 39278673,
            "album_name": "DISCO (Deluxe)",
            "artist_id": 7712,
            "artist_name": "Kylie Minogue",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Kylie-Minogue\/Say-Something?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Kylie-Minogue\/Say-Something\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
            "restricted": 0,
            "updated_time": "2020-07-23T16:04:00Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": [
                {
                  "music_genre": {
                    "music_genre_id": 34,
                    "music_genre_parent_id": 0,
                    "music_genre_name": "Music",
                    "music_genre_name_extended": "Music",
                    "music_genre_vanity": "Music"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I used https://app.quicktype.io/ to get something like this:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final jsonToDart = jsonToDartFromMap(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

JsonToDart jsonToDartFromMap(String str) => JsonToDart.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String jsonToDartToMap(JsonToDart data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class JsonToDart {
  JsonToDart({
    this.message,
  });

  Message message;

  factory JsonToDart.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => JsonToDart(
    message: Message.fromMap(json["message"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "message": message.toMap(),
  };
}

class Message {
  Message({
    this.header,
    this.body,
  });

  Header header;
  Body body;

  factory Message.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Message(
    header: Header.fromMap(json["header"]),
    body: Body.fromMap(json["body"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "header": header.toMap(),
    "body": body.toMap(),
  };
}

class Body {
  Body({
    this.trackList,
  });

  List<TrackList> trackList;

  factory Body.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Body(
    trackList: List<TrackList>.from(json["track_list"].map((x) => TrackList.fromMap(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "track_list": List<dynamic>.from(trackList.map((x) => x.toMap())),
  };
}

class TrackList {
  TrackList({
    this.track,
  });

  Track track;

  factory TrackList.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TrackList(
    track: Track.fromMap(json["track"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "track": track.toMap(),
  };
}

class Track {
  Track({
    this.trackId,
    this.trackName,
    this.trackNameTranslationList,
    this.trackRating,
    this.commontrackId,
    this.instrumental,
    this.explicit,
    this.hasLyrics,
    this.hasSubtitles,
    this.hasRichsync,
    this.numFavourite,
    this.albumId,
    this.albumName,
    this.artistId,
    this.artistName,
    this.trackShareUrl,
    this.trackEditUrl,
    this.restricted,
    this.updatedTime,
    this.primaryGenres,
  });

  int trackId;
  String trackName;
  List<dynamic> trackNameTranslationList;
  int trackRating;
  int commontrackId;
  int instrumental;
  int explicit;
  int hasLyrics;
  int hasSubtitles;
  int hasRichsync;
  int numFavourite;
  int albumId;
  String albumName;
  int artistId;
  String artistName;
  String trackShareUrl;
  String trackEditUrl;
  int restricted;
  DateTime updatedTime;
  PrimaryGenres primaryGenres;

  factory Track.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Track(
    trackId: json["track_id"],
    trackName: json["track_name"],
    trackNameTranslationList: List<dynamic>.from(json["track_name_translation_list"].map((x) => x)),
    trackRating: json["track_rating"],
    commontrackId: json["commontrack_id"],
    instrumental: json["instrumental"],
    explicit: json["explicit"],
    hasLyrics: json["has_lyrics"],
    hasSubtitles: json["has_subtitles"],
    hasRichsync: json["has_richsync"],
    numFavourite: json["num_favourite"],
    albumId: json["album_id"],
    albumName: json["album_name"],
    artistId: json["artist_id"],
    artistName: json["artist_name"],
    trackShareUrl: json["track_share_url"],
    trackEditUrl: json["track_edit_url"],
    restricted: json["restricted"],
    updatedTime: DateTime.parse(json["updated_time"]),
    primaryGenres: PrimaryGenres.fromMap(json["primary_genres"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "track_id": trackId,
    "track_name": trackName,
    "track_name_translation_list": List<dynamic>.from(trackNameTranslationList.map((x) => x)),
    "track_rating": trackRating,
    "commontrack_id": commontrackId,
    "instrumental": instrumental,
    "explicit": explicit,
    "has_lyrics": hasLyrics,
    "has_subtitles": hasSubtitles,
    "has_richsync": hasRichsync,
    "num_favourite": numFavourite,
    "album_id": albumId,
    "album_name": albumName,
    "artist_id": artistId,
    "artist_name": artistName,
    "track_share_url": trackShareUrl,
    "track_edit_url": trackEditUrl,
    "restricted": restricted,
    "updated_time": updatedTime.toIso8601String(),
    "primary_genres": primaryGenres.toMap(),
  };
}

class PrimaryGenres {
  PrimaryGenres({
    this.musicGenreList,
  });

  List<MusicGenreList> musicGenreList;

  factory PrimaryGenres.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PrimaryGenres(
    musicGenreList: List<MusicGenreList>.from(json["music_genre_list"].map((x) => MusicGenreList.fromMap(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "music_genre_list": List<dynamic>.from(musicGenreList.map((x) => x.toMap())),
  };
}

class MusicGenreList {
  MusicGenreList({
    this.musicGenre,
  });

  MusicGenre musicGenre;

  factory MusicGenreList.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MusicGenreList(
    musicGenre: MusicGenre.fromMap(json["music_genre"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "music_genre": musicGenre.toMap(),
  };
}

class MusicGenre {
  MusicGenre({
    this.musicGenreId,
    this.musicGenreParentId,
    this.musicGenreName,
    this.musicGenreNameExtended,
    this.musicGenreVanity,
  });

  int musicGenreId;
  int musicGenreParentId;
  String musicGenreName;
  String musicGenreNameExtended;
  String musicGenreVanity;

  factory MusicGenre.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MusicGenre(
    musicGenreId: json["music_genre_id"],
    musicGenreParentId: json["music_genre_parent_id"],
    musicGenreName: json["music_genre_name"],
    musicGenreNameExtended: json["music_genre_name_extended"],
    musicGenreVanity: json["music_genre_vanity"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "music_genre_id": musicGenreId,
    "music_genre_parent_id": musicGenreParentId,
    "music_genre_name": musicGenreName,
    "music_genre_name_extended": musicGenreNameExtended,
    "music_genre_vanity": musicGenreVanity,
  };
}

class Header {
  Header({
    this.statusCode,
    this.executeTime,
  });

  int statusCode;
  double executeTime;

  factory Header.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Header(
    statusCode: json["status_code"],
    executeTime: json["execute_time"].toDouble(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "status_code": statusCode,
    "execute_time": executeTime,
  };
}
```

I used this in the main function:

```
  Future<JsonToDart> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(url1);
    print("ssssssssssssssss");
    print(response.body);
    return jsonToDartFromMap(response.body);
  }
```

But I dont know how to proceed from here. I have to take the values of trackId,trackName,artistName,albumName and display in a listView.Many tutorials have different styles and this JSON data I just can't understand how to simplify it.Please help

Comment: Are you trying to display the items in the `track_list` Array?

Comment: @ JideGuru  yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check out the Example that I have created :
This is the json you provided

```
{
    "message": {
      "header": {
        "status_code": 200,
        "execute_time": 0.021989107131958
      },
      "body": {
        "track_list": [
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 200357565,
              "track_name": "The Climb Back",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 99,
              "commontrack_id": 113835591,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 1,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 1,
              "num_favourite": 20,
              "album_id": 39278073,
              "album_name": "Lewis Street",
              "artist_id": 486280,
              "artist_name": "J. Cole",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/J-Cole\/The-Climb-Back?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/J-Cole\/The-Climb-Back\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-07-23T14:02:17Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 200187374,
              "track_name": "POPSTAR (feat. Drake)",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 99,
              "commontrack_id": 113684105,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 1,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 1,
              "num_favourite": 6,
              "album_id": 39216808,
              "album_name": "POPSTAR (feat. Drake) - Single",
              "artist_id": 24704782,
              "artist_name": "DJ Khaled feat. Drake, Lil Wayne & Rick Ross",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/DJ-Khaled-feat-Drake-Lil-Wayne-Rick-Ross\/POPSTAR-Drake?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/DJ-Khaled-feat-Drake-Lil-Wayne-Rick-Ross\/POPSTAR-Drake\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-07-17T13:38:30Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 200102123,
              "track_name": "What's Love Got to Do with It",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 99,
              "commontrack_id": 113606423,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 0,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 1,
              "num_favourite": 18,
              "album_id": 39186667,
              "album_name": "What's Love Got to Do with It",
              "artist_id": 45989671,
              "artist_name": "Kygo feat. Tina Turner",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Kygo-Tina-Turner\/What-s-Love-Got-to-Do-with-It?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Kygo-Tina-Turner\/What-s-Love-Got-to-Do-with-It\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-07-23T06:28:49Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 194169151,
              "track_name": "Blinding Lights",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 100,
              "commontrack_id": 104185748,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 0,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 1,
              "num_favourite": 5583,
              "album_id": 37216011,
              "album_name": "After Hours",
              "artist_id": 13937035,
              "artist_name": "The Weeknd",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/The-Weeknd-3\/Blinding-Lights?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/The-Weeknd-3\/Blinding-Lights\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-07-09T11:24:05Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": [
                  {
                    "music_genre": {
                      "music_genre_id": 7,
                      "music_genre_parent_id": 34,
                      "music_genre_name": "Electronic",
                      "music_genre_name_extended": "Electronic",
                      "music_genre_vanity": "Electronic"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 198421234,
              "track_name": "Savage Love (Laxed - Siren Beat)",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 100,
              "commontrack_id": 112136372,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 1,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 1,
              "num_favourite": 454,
              "album_id": 38617941,
              "album_name": "Savage Love (Laxed - Siren Beat) - Single",
              "artist_id": 45643815,
              "artist_name": "Jawsh 685 feat. Jason Derulo",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Jawsh-685-Jason-Derulo\/Savage-Love-Laxed-Siren-Beat?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Jawsh-685-Jason-Derulo\/Savage-Love-Laxed-Siren-Beat\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-07-09T13:06:43Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 189626475,
              "track_name": "Watermelon Sugar",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 100,
              "commontrack_id": 104939195,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 0,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 1,
              "num_favourite": 567,
              "album_id": 36101498,
              "album_name": "Fine Line",
              "artist_id": 24505463,
              "artist_name": "Harry Styles",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Harry-Styles\/Watermelon-Sugar-2?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Harry-Styles\/Watermelon-Sugar-2\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2019-12-12T16:57:16Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 192324206,
              "track_name": "One Margarita",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 99,
              "commontrack_id": 107705631,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 0,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 1,
              "num_favourite": 62,
              "album_id": 36710192,
              "album_name": "Born Here Live Here Die Here",
              "artist_id": 360257,
              "artist_name": "Luke Bryan",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Luke-Bryan\/One-Margarita?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Luke-Bryan\/One-Margarita\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-03-13T08:54:41Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": [
                  {
                    "music_genre": {
                      "music_genre_id": 34,
                      "music_genre_parent_id": 0,
                      "music_genre_name": "Music",
                      "music_genre_name_extended": "Music",
                      "music_genre_vanity": "Music"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 195445553,
              "track_name": "ROCKSTAR (feat. Roddy Ricch)",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 99,
              "commontrack_id": 109586143,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 1,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 1,
              "num_favourite": 687,
              "album_id": 37641727,
              "album_name": "BLAME IT ON BABY",
              "artist_id": 45035319,
              "artist_name": "DaBaby feat. Roddy Ricch",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/DaBaby-Roddy-Ricch\/ROCKSTAR-Roddy-Ricch?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/DaBaby-Roddy-Ricch\/ROCKSTAR-Roddy-Ricch\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-06-22T12:43:00Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 200340862,
              "track_name": "Patience",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 98,
              "commontrack_id": 113824017,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 0,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 0,
              "num_favourite": 4,
              "album_id": 39273295,
              "album_name": "Patience",
              "artist_id": 156,
              "artist_name": "Chris Cornell",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Chris-Cornell\/Patience?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Chris-Cornell\/Patience\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-07-21T20:15:22Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "track": {
              "track_id": 200360270,
              "track_name": "Say Something",
              "track_name_translation_list": [],
              "track_rating": 1,
              "commontrack_id": 113837622,
              "instrumental": 0,
              "explicit": 0,
              "has_lyrics": 1,
              "has_subtitles": 1,
              "has_richsync": 0,
              "num_favourite": 0,
              "album_id": 39278673,
              "album_name": "DISCO (Deluxe)",
              "artist_id": 7712,
              "artist_name": "Kylie Minogue",
              "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Kylie-Minogue\/Say-Something?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Kylie-Minogue\/Say-Something\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=n%2Fa%3A1409620463618",
              "restricted": 0,
              "updated_time": "2020-07-23T16:04:00Z",
              "primary_genres": {
                "music_genre_list": [
                  {
                    "music_genre": {
                      "music_genre_id": 34,
                      "music_genre_parent_id": 0,
                      "music_genre_name": "Music",
                      "music_genre_name_extended": "Music",
                      "music_genre_vanity": "Music"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the model for the json :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final track = trackFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Track trackFromJson(String str) => Track.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String trackToJson(Track data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Track {
    Track({
        this.message,
    });

    Message message;

    factory Track.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Track(
        message: Message.fromJson(json["message"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "message": message.toJson(),
    };
}

class Message {
    Message({
        this.header,
        this.body,
    });

    Header header;
    Body body;

    factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Message(
        header: Header.fromJson(json["header"]),
        body: Body.fromJson(json["body"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "header": header.toJson(),
        "body": body.toJson(),
    };
}

class Body {
    Body({
        this.trackList,
    });

    List<TrackList> trackList;

    factory Body.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Body(
        trackList: List<TrackList>.from(json["track_list"].map((x) => TrackList.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "track_list": List<dynamic>.from(trackList.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class TrackList {
    TrackList({
        this.track,
    });

    TrackClass track;

    factory TrackList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TrackList(
        track: TrackClass.fromJson(json["track"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "track": track.toJson(),
    };
}

class TrackClass {
    TrackClass({
        this.trackId,
        this.trackName,
        this.trackNameTranslationList,
        this.trackRating,
        this.commontrackId,
        this.instrumental,
        this.explicit,
        this.hasLyrics,
        this.hasSubtitles,
        this.hasRichsync,
        this.numFavourite,
        this.albumId,
        this.albumName,
        this.artistId,
        this.artistName,
        this.trackShareUrl,
        this.trackEditUrl,
        this.restricted,
        this.updatedTime,
        this.primaryGenres,
    });

    int trackId;
    String trackName;
    List<dynamic> trackNameTranslationList;
    int trackRating;
    int commontrackId;
    int instrumental;
    int explicit;
    int hasLyrics;
    int hasSubtitles;
    int hasRichsync;
    int numFavourite;
    int albumId;
    String albumName;
    int artistId;
    String artistName;
    String trackShareUrl;
    String trackEditUrl;
    int restricted;
    DateTime updatedTime;
    PrimaryGenres primaryGenres;

    factory TrackClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TrackClass(
        trackId: json["track_id"],
        trackName: json["track_name"],
        trackNameTranslationList: List<dynamic>.from(json["track_name_translation_list"].map((x) => x)),
        trackRating: json["track_rating"],
        commontrackId: json["commontrack_id"],
        instrumental: json["instrumental"],
        explicit: json["explicit"],
        hasLyrics: json["has_lyrics"],
        hasSubtitles: json["has_subtitles"],
        hasRichsync: json["has_richsync"],
        numFavourite: json["num_favourite"],
        albumId: json["album_id"],
        albumName: json["album_name"],
        artistId: json["artist_id"],
        artistName: json["artist_name"],
        trackShareUrl: json["track_share_url"],
        trackEditUrl: json["track_edit_url"],
        restricted: json["restricted"],
        updatedTime: DateTime.parse(json["updated_time"]),
        primaryGenres: PrimaryGenres.fromJson(json["primary_genres"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "track_id": trackId,
        "track_name": trackName,
        "track_name_translation_list": List<dynamic>.from(trackNameTranslationList.map((x) => x)),
        "track_rating": trackRating,
        "commontrack_id": commontrackId,
        "instrumental": instrumental,
        "explicit": explicit,
        "has_lyrics": hasLyrics,
        "has_subtitles": hasSubtitles,
        "has_richsync": hasRichsync,
        "num_favourite": numFavourite,
        "album_id": albumId,
        "album_name": albumName,
        "artist_id": artistId,
        "artist_name": artistName,
        "track_share_url": trackShareUrl,
        "track_edit_url": trackEditUrl,
        "restricted": restricted,
        "updated_time": updatedTime.toIso8601String(),
        "primary_genres": primaryGenres.toJson(),
    };
}

class PrimaryGenres {
    PrimaryGenres({
        this.musicGenreList,
    });

    List<MusicGenreList> musicGenreList;

    factory PrimaryGenres.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PrimaryGenres(
        musicGenreList: List<MusicGenreList>.from(json["music_genre_list"].map((x) => MusicGenreList.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "music_genre_list": List<dynamic>.from(musicGenreList.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class MusicGenreList {
    MusicGenreList({
        this.musicGenre,
    });

    MusicGenre musicGenre;

    factory MusicGenreList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MusicGenreList(
        musicGenre: MusicGenre.fromJson(json["music_genre"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "music_genre": musicGenre.toJson(),
    };
}

class MusicGenre {
    MusicGenre({
        this.musicGenreId,
        this.musicGenreParentId,
        this.musicGenreName,
        this.musicGenreNameExtended,
        this.musicGenreVanity,
    });

    int musicGenreId;
    int musicGenreParentId;
    String musicGenreName;
    String musicGenreNameExtended;
    String musicGenreVanity;

    factory MusicGenre.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MusicGenre(
        musicGenreId: json["music_genre_id"],
        musicGenreParentId: json["music_genre_parent_id"],
        musicGenreName: json["music_genre_name"],
        musicGenreNameExtended: json["music_genre_name_extended"],
        musicGenreVanity: json["music_genre_vanity"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "music_genre_id": musicGenreId,
        "music_genre_parent_id": musicGenreParentId,
        "music_genre_name": musicGenreName,
        "music_genre_name_extended": musicGenreNameExtended,
        "music_genre_vanity": musicGenreVanity,
    };
}

class Header {
    Header({
        this.statusCode,
        this.executeTime,
    });

    int statusCode;
    double executeTime;

    factory Header.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Header(
        statusCode: json["status_code"],
        executeTime: json["execute_time"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status_code": statusCode,
        "execute_time": executeTime,
    };
}
```

This is the ui for the model:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_parsing_example/models.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<TrackList> trackList = List();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    final track = trackFromJson(data);

    trackList = track.message.body.trackList;
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: _isLoading
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: trackList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var item = trackList[index];
                  return Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Track Id :' + item.track.trackId.toString()),
                        Text('Track Name:' + item.track.trackName.toString()),
                        Text(
                            'Artist Name :' + item.track.artistName.toString()),
                        Text('Album Name :' + item.track.albumName.toString())
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }));
  }
}
```

From the function what I see is you can do like this:

```
Future<List<TrackList>> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(url1);
    print("ssssssssssssssss");
    print(response.body);
     var item = trackFromJson(response.body);

    return item.body.track_list;
  }
```

Check out the example and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah it works,Thanks man...but still I have a problem. I have to fetch the response by  var response = await http.get(url1);    But an error stating it should be in Map and not list comes.I dont know how to work it out with Maps after this line Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);

Comment: I have to get the response by webservice, So I have to use http.get(url)  method to get the response .After that I have to take the response and use the respose.body of it and use Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body); –                  But after that I dont know how to proceed

Comment: Just check the edit where I have changed you code get data code, return the List<TrackList> get the trackList data.

Comment: item.body.track_list shows an error so I replace with track.message.body.trackList; by changing item to track.Now the webservice is down.Anyhow thanks a lot for your help man,it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to create your own model classes in which you perform parsing mechanism. One of the examples would be user class created like this:

```
class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String phoneNumber;
  String emailAddress;

  User({
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.emailAddress,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      firstName: json["first_name"],
      lastName: json["last_name"],
      phoneNumber: json["phone_number"],
      emailAddress: json["email_address"],
    );
  }
}
```

After you are done creating your base model that holds entire tree you posted above, you go ahead and start parsing array elements such as `track_list` by creating `Track` model listing all the track properties. Once you have your base model, Track model and all the properties of the Track model, you would need to link that track list to your base model and it's done like this:

```
List jsonList = json.decode(serverResponse.body)['track_list'];
trackList: List.generate(jsonList.length, (i) => Track.fromJson(jsonList[i]));
```

When you complete linking base model, list of tracks and parsing of a single track, you will also need to parse inner Track lists in the same way, but basics of the parsing mechanism I listed above should be enough to get you through the entire process of parsing JSON object and JSON inner list objects.